# file_get_contents() security issue on local domain only with CentOS security settings

Tags: php, linux, ssh, centos

I know there are a hundred posts about `file_get_contents()` on SO but nothing seems to solve my problem:

Everything was working fine fifteen minutes ago, until I ran some security stuff via SSH. I added some `iptables` rules and I file_get_contents and I ran `service proftpd restart` and a few installs/uninstalls which seems to have disabled PHP's `fopen()` functions somehow.

In php.ini, I have: `allow_url_fopen = on` & `extension=php_openssl.dll` on

**I'm trying a simple test:** (this file loads fine via the browser)

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.this-domain.com/logo.gif");
//...failed to open stream:HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found...

//However both of the following work absolutely fine:

echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/");
echo file_get_contents("/home/user/domains/this-domain.com/private_html/media/logospin.gif");
```

I cannot change the file_get_contents() code (to cURL or otherwise) - this is a server settings issue. Possibly something to do with the firewall. Can someone please suggest a fix?

Comment: 404 isn't php's problem. your url is incorrect, or the request is hitting the wrong site.

Comment: I didnt change the code - I just ran some SSH commands to update security

Comment: well, I fail to see how restarting an ftp server would affect php running inside apache...

Comment: Why don't you give us the actual URL? SSH changes shouldn't affect your webserver at all.

Comment: Strangely, trying to get contents from a different domain works fine. Its only when the content I'm trying to fetch is on this domain that it breaks

Comment: So try out `curl` on the command line and see what happens. Maybe `www.this-domain.com` is pointed somewhere you don't expect with `/etc/hosts` or something. Chances are it's a problem with your config, not PHP.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` works fine, connects to the URL and from remote web server receives `HTTP 404` error code. So either you have wrong URL or the file on webserver doesn't exist (404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact a DNS issue. `file_get_contents()` was bizarrely routing through our backup nameservers (ns3 & ns4) for some reason, while browsers were routing through the primary nameservers (ns1 & ns2). Unlike the primaries, the backups point to a different server, which does not yet have identical files - hence the unusual 404.

I had set up these backup nameservers only a few hours before tinkering with the firewall etc and by the time they propagated, it looked very much like the ssh commands had taken `file_get_contents()` offline.

Thanks for all the comments guys - very much appreciated.

Comment: Any ideas why `file_get_contents` would route through different nameservers to the browser?